# [React]: Uploading file, Changing state to show preview, then waiting for upload before submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, axios

I'm a bit of a beginner at React, and have tried running an async function to achieve this, however it kept breaking and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

What the app is currently doing:

1. I input a file and click upload in order to post it
2. The file uploads and sets the state, showing a preview
3. I then click submit to submit the form.

What it should do

1. Automatically "upload" the file once I input it (onChange)
2. Wait until the file is done uploading to firestore before it allowing the form to be submitted

**My Handlers**

```
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.screamImage === "") {
      this.props.postScream({
        productName: this.state.productName,
        body: this.state.body,
        price: this.state.price,
        charge: this.state.charge,
        screamImage:
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth-development-2fa3c.appspot.com/o/no-img2.jpg?alt=media",
      });
    } else
      this.props.postScream({
        productName: this.state.productName,
        body: this.state.body,
        price: this.state.price,
        charge: this.state.charge,
        screamImage: this.screamData,
      });
  };

  fileOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.files[0],
    });
  };

  fileUploadHandler = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      "image",
      this.state.screamImage,
      this.state.screamImage.name
    );
    axios.post("/scream/image", formData).then((res) => {
      this.screamData = res.data.screamImageUrl;
      console.log(this.screamData);
      return this.screamData;
    });
  };
```

**The Return**

```
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    name="screamImage"
                    onChange={this.fileOnChange}
                  />
                  <Button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload</Button>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submitButton}
                    disabled={loading}
                  >
                    Submit
                    {loading && (
                      <CircularProgress
                        size={30}
                        className={classes.progressSpinner}
                      />
                    )}
```

Sorry if this is just a simple fix, I can't seem to get the hang of async functions yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that won't work as you expect it to.

The `onChange` is only changing the state and not starting the upload function:

```js
fileOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.files[0],
    });
  };
```

a quiq fix would be to just call the function with the `setState` callback like here:

```js
fileOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.files[0],
    },()=>{this.fileUploadHandler()});
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue here is that when I try this fix, it will set the state first and then the file upload, meaning the preview gets broken. Also, if I choose the file and click "cancel" there's no data to be read, which also breaks it

Comment: Can you pls update your question to be more detailed and share your whole file. There are a lot of parts we can't see but we can break with our snippets.

Comment: Hey Tarik, appreciate your time! I actually ended up figuring it out, I'll post the answer shortly :)

Comment: Hi, great to hear that. It would be awesome if you can share the answe for other if they got a similar or same questions.

Comment: Just posted it below! In the future I'll be changing my code to make it so it will read the file with a file reader and only post on form Submit, will post that too once I have that done

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in case anyone has the same issue with handling file change! A big problem I had was an error stating that the formData "value" was not a Blob. Here's my fix, I had to define "image" as the target file and then use that as the value, before setting state:

```
fileOnChange = (event) => {
    const screamImage = event.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", screamImage, Image.name);
    axios.post("/scream/image", formData).then((res => {
      this.screamData = res.data.screamImageUrl;
      console.log(this.screamData)
      return this.screamData
    })).then(()=> {
      this.setState({
        screamImage: this.screamData,
    });
    });
  };
```